# Protractor: Unable to pass text into text box

Tags: javascript, protractor, aurelia

I must be missing something very obvious with this but when I try to pass text into an input field, the script doesn't fail but it also isn't entering text into the text field. If it makes any difference, the text field will only accept numbers.

This is the html

```html
<input type="number" class="form-control au-target form-control-warning" value.bind="bidAmount &amp; debounce:500 &amp; validate" au-target-id="126" placeholder="Enter Amount">
```

This is how I try it on my page object file

```js
var amount = 60;
return element(by.valueBind('bidAmount &amp; debounce:500 &amp; validate"')).clear().sendKeys(amount);
```

I've also tried `by.cssContainingText()` and `by.css()` but neither are working

Comment: element(by.xpath(".//input[contains(@class,'form-control au-target')]")).sendKeys(amount); try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try,

```
$("input[placeholder='Enter Amount']").clear().sendKeys('hello');
```

or more explicit

```
element(by.css("input[placeholder='Enter Amount']")).clear().sendKeys('hello');
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you get it with :

```
$('input[type="number"][class="form-control au-target form-control-warning"]').clear().sendKeys(amount);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I get an error saying `no element found using locator: By(css selector, input[type`